# Is it possible add emoji to log in python

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

can we add emoji in our log report?
i got the below error when i add an emoji

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2795' in position 75: character maps to <undefined>
Call stack:
  File "c:\Users\Lukmana\Desktop\user_count\usercount.py", line 121, in <module>
    logger.info("-Total count initiated-➕")
Message: '-Total count initiated-➕'
Arguments: ()
Check logfile 'C:\user_count\usercount.20.103.log' for details
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, just use an appropriate encoding. The following example script

```
import logging

fh = logging.FileHandler('emojis.log', mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
root = logging.getLogger()
root.addHandler(fh)
root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
root.debug('\N{smiling face with sunglasses}')
root.debug('\N{rolling on the floor laughing}')
```

outputs emojis to `emojis.log`:

```
$ more emojis.log
```

Note that some versions of terminals on Windows may not show emojis properly. And you can of course use `\U` escape sequences as well as the `\N` examples above.

Comment: no parameter encoding